# Magento does not switch language by URL

Tags: magento2

I have my Magento 2 shop at domain.local/shop/ address. I have Croatian (HR) store view by default and also English (en), Deutsch (de) store views.

The problem is that when I open domain.local/shop/en/ or domain.local/shop/de/ (I have store codes enabled for urls), I get the Croatian language though language switcher shows EN or DE. Only when I manually switch to HR and then back to EN or DE, I finally get the appropriate store view.

Why doesn't language switching work by URL?